# uploading an image to 'uploads' directory in my project root directory using php

Tags: php, image-upload

I am new to php and working on image upload.

When user submits an image the script should move the submitted image to my 'uploads' folder which is located at my project root directory.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('database.php');
ini_set('max_exection_time', 60);
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
   header('location: http://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~baehy/team72index.php');
} else {
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['userid'] . "<br>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
//get file from the form and get following information
$file = $_FILES['coverimage'];
$fileName = $_FILES['coverimage']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['coverimage']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['coverimage']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['coverimage']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['coverimage']['type'];

//retrieve file extention using explode()
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
//because some file extentions might be in capital letters
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
  if($fileError === 0){
    //if the size of the file is lesser than 1M kb = 1000mb
    if($fileSize < 1000000){
      $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
      chmod('/uploads/',0777);
      echo "permission granted to uploads directory!" . "<br>";
      $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
      move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
      echo $fileNameNew . "<br>";
      echo "Successfully uploaded your file" . "<br>";
    } else {
      echo "Your file is too big to upload" . "<br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "There was an error uploading your file" . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "This file extention is not allowed to be uploaded" . "<br>";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `recipe` (title, category, description, coverimage)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$category."', '".$description."', '".$fileName."')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result){
  echo "successfully added to database";
} else {
  echo "failed to add to database";
}
$showImage = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `coverimage` FROM `recipe`");
}
}

?>
```

I am using winscp as a server since this is the school project and file_uploads directive is already set to "on"
Here is my phpinfo.php link: http://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~baehy/phpinfo.php

I am not getting any images uploaded to my 'uploads' folder.
Any comments is appreciated, please let me know which correction is needed! Thank you all in advance!

p.s) my project root folder is located at desktop/project if that matters

Comment: enable error reporting, it will bork on move_uploaded_file due to permissions, or above as `/uploads/` is not relative. also fix the SQL injection before your schools server gets hacked (see related column to right)